# how to Download and unarchive a tarball only once using Ansible

Tags: ansible, devops, redhat

I am trying to download and unarchive a tarball onto remote machine using ansible and each time i run the ansible, below task should not download or unarchive again. How can i skip the download and unarchive each time i run the ansible?

```
- name: Download/unarchive Packages
  unarchive:
    src: http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/cdh/5/zookeeper-3.4.5-cdh5.16.2.tar.gz
    dest: /tmp
    owner: test
    group: test
    remote_src: yes
    force: no
    creates: "/tmp/zookeeper"
```

Comment: As per the documentation for [unarchive](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/unarchive_module.html), the task will be skipped if the path mentioned in `creates:` exists. With what directory name does that archive extract? Perhaps you should have `creates: /tmp/zookeeper-3.4.5-cdh5.16.2`?

Answer (score 2):

The Tar archive extracts to `zookeeper-3.4.5-cdh5.16.2`. You should mention this in `creates:`

```yaml
- name: Download/unarchive Packages
  unarchive:
    src: http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/cdh/5/zookeeper-3.4.5-cdh5.16.2.tar.gz
    dest: /tmp
    owner: test
    group: test
    remote_src: yes
    force: no
    creates: /tmp/zookeeper-3.4.5-cdh5.16.2
```